# Целочисленное деление с округлением вверх

Tags: c++, c

Есть ли оператор целочисленного деления с округлением вверх?
Чтобы было так:

```
1 / N = 1
2 / N = 1
...
N / N = 1
N + 1 / N = 2
N + 2 / N = 2
...
2N / N = 2
2N + 1 / N = 3
...
```

Или как это можно реализовать без использования математики, только на встроенных примитивах и целых типах данных?

UPD: встроенного нет, тогда можно ли упростить следующую функцию:

```
int div_up(int x, int y)
{
    return x / y + (x%y ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Comment: Встроеного нету, но можно обьявить свой класс и назначить ему операторы.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Не знаю, на сколько это проще, но можно так

```
int div_up(int x, int y)
{
    return (x + y - 1) / y;
}
```

Ну и подумать, что такое округление вверх для отрицательных чисел

**Update**

Чтобы избежать возможного переполнения, выражение можно переписать так

```
int div_up(int x, int y)
{
    return (x - 1) / y + 1;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, ваше решение проще

Comment: подождём, тут обитает много умных людей, может еще присоветуют)

Comment: Возможное переполнение (в `x + y`) не смущает?

Comment: Здорово,  вместе с `ret`  укладывается в 5 команд (на 3 меньше, чем в вопросе)

Comment: Второй вариант, к сожалению, некрасиво ведет себя на нулевом делимом.

Comment: @AnT Я так понимаю, что тут либо переполнение вверх, либо переполнение вниз

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, во втором варианте если х = 0, у = 2 .. , то результат будет 1, когда должен быть 0. Вариант без переполнения и без условных операторов мне придумать не удалось(

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать функцию `ceil()` из `<math.h>`.
Примеры можно посмотреть по ссылке: [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/ceil/)

Comment: Неоправданное привлечение плавающей арифметики в чисто целочисленную задачу - этого всегда желательно избегать.

Answer (score 0):

Встретилась похожая задача на вычисление количества байт, в зависимости от количества бит или от количества двухбайтовых регистров. Для C++ получилось вот такое универсальное решение, защищенное от переполнения и подходящее для всех беззнаковых значений:

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
inline constexpr T get_bit_count(T quantity) {
  static_assert(std::is_unsigned<T>::value, "Required unsigned integral type");
  return (quantity >> 3) + static_cast<T>(static_cast<bool>(quantity & 0x7));
}
static_assert(get_bit_count(0u) == 0, "");
static_assert(get_bit_count(1u) == 1, "");
static_assert(get_bit_count(8u) == 1, "");
static_assert(get_bit_count(9u) == 2, "");
static_assert(get_bit_count(0xFFFFu) == 0x2000, "");
static_assert(get_bit_count(0xFFFFFFFFu) == 0x20000000, "");
#ifdef UINT64_MAX
static_assert(get_bit_count(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFu) == 0x2000000000000000, "");
#endif

template <typename T>
inline constexpr T get_reg_count(T quantity) {
  static_assert(std::is_unsigned<T>::value, "Required unsigned integral type");
  assert(quantity < static_cast<T>(1) << ((sizeof(T) << 3) - 1));
  return quantity << 1;
}
static_assert(get_reg_count(0u) == 0, "");
static_assert(get_reg_count(1u) == 2, "");
static_assert(get_reg_count(2u) == 4, "");
static_assert(get_reg_count(3u) == 6, "");
static_assert(get_reg_count(0x7FFFu) == 0xFFFE, "");
static_assert(get_reg_count(0x7FFFFFFFu) == 0xFFFFFFFE, "");
#ifdef UINT64_MAX
static_assert(get_reg_count(0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFu) == 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE, "");
#endif
```

Comment: Вы бы написали подробнее, что конкретнее делают ваши функции. Например, `get_bit_count` не похожа на функцию, возвращающую количество единичных бит в числе, хотя название намекает на такое поведение... И как их вообще применить для целочисленного деления с округлением вверх?

Comment: @wololo get_bit_count - вычисляет количество байт занимаемой памяти в зависимости от полученного количества бит. get_reg_count - вычисляет количество байт занимаемой памяти в зависимости от полученного количества двухбайтовых регистров. Применяется алгоритм быстрого целочисленного деления с округлением вверх для первой функции. Данный алгоритм будет работать, если делитель - число, полученное возведением двойки в степень. В данном случае делитель - это 8, 8 - это 2 в степени 3. Вторая функция использует аналогичный алгоритм, только с операцией умножения